# Issue related to view pager and circle page indicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I have four pages/screens in my view pager and I am using Circle page indicator for displaying the position of the screen. It works perfectly.

Now I need to add one more indicator circle even though the screen count is 4. Up on crossing the 4 the screen, I want to display another activity.

I have searched and found a solution for moving to another activity before the fake page (5th page is shown). Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                // skip fake page (first), go to last page
                if (position == 4) {
                    //instead of activity call, I am checking whether it's working or not
                    ((ViewPager) container).setCurrentItem(0, false);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }
```

But the problem is that, When I am doing this, the circle page indicator stops working.

Here is code for setting the adapter to circle page indicator:

```
mVpAdvertisement.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mCpIndicator.setViewPager(mVpAdvertisement);
        mCpIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {               
                // on changing the pages during swipe
                if(position==0)
                {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
            {

            }
        });
```

I want to display 5 circles and upon swiping from 4th screen in view pager, I want application to display another activity, without showing the 5th screen (dummy screen) in view pager.

This is the library I am using: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: @ChiragShah: No. Finally I had to drop that idea and use a "Get started" button

Comment: i got it.Want to see that??

Comment: @ChiragShah: Yes, please post it as answer

Comment: @ChiragShah Would be great if you could post the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late, even the person posted the question got the answer also, but as it may help others to find the quick answer i am posting the answer.

Use two image(circle) for indicator one is for off and another for on. use frame layout to show the indicator. when user slide the viewPager just change the image. You can download the complete solutions which i have developed and working fine for me.
http://javaant.com/viewpager-with-circle-indicator-in-android